# How to use 3rd Party Libraries in Ios Extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous

I want to use `AsynchronousImageView` and `AsynchronousNetworking` classes in `Keyboard Extension`. Can you Please tell How to use this classes in code. I has implemented `AsynchronousImageView` code its compile perfect but during run time it will crash..

**my code is:**

```
self.imageVw.ImageUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gamacompass.com/imagesuploaded/000001631/_thumbnails/sku_3451_000001631_large.jpg"];
```

Answer (score 0):

As i found in [`apple documentation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2) we need one flag to use that `library` in `extension`.

**Use any API marked in header files with the NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE macro, or similar unavailability macro, or any API in an unavailable framework**